# Django Rest Framework Viewsets / Database Locks

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, restful-architecture

Hi there so i am using `Django Rest Framework 3.1` and i was wondering if its possible to "protect" my viewsets / database against writes in a per user basis?

In other words if 1 user is saving something the other one cannot save and it either waits till the first user finishes or returns some kind of error.

I tried looking for this answer but couldn't find it.

Is this behavior already implemented? if not how can i achieve this in practice?

**UPDATE** after some more thinking:

This is just a theory still, it needs more thinking, but if we use a Queue (Redis or Rabbitmq) we can put all synchronization writes requests in the queue instead of processing them right away and in conjunction with some user specific lock variable (maybe in the user sessions db table) we can ask if there are any users in front of us belonging to the same proponent and if those users have finished writing their updates or not (using the lock)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Database transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) will provide some of the safety you're looking for, I think. If a number of database operations are wrapped in a transaction, they are applied to the database together, so a sequence of operations cannot fail mid-way through and leave the database in an invalid state.

Other users will see the results of the operations as if they were applied all at once, or not at all (in the case of an error).

Comment: but what happens to the second user that is trying to write to a database that has a transaction from the first user? is it going to raise an exception?

Comment: I believe that depends on the database you're using. For example, the [documentation for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) lists a number of modes so you can specify how concurrent transactions behave.

Comment: i am not sure your answer applies nicely to my case because i believe this decisions should be made at a application level still not the db. when you get to the db you already know you can write otherwise it seems to me that treating the exceptions and passing them along to DRF will be more complicated. I made an update in my original post with an idea i had. please let me know what you think.

Comment: in addition i dont want the second user to override what the first user wrote so i must return a specific error

Comment: Could you do something simple like have the users send 'change' requests, with a before and after value for each field to change? Then if the before value doesn't match the current value from the DB you know there's been a change in the meantime, so you can respond with an error.

Comment: Don't know if you ever found what you were looking for, but it sounds like you wanted "optimistic locking" (essentially what joerick described). There are multiple Django add-ons for implementing it, but the basic gist is that each model has a simple version counter. A save() operation checks the counter in the db vs. what it has in memory and raises an exception if it fails. Like you said, how you handle that exception is up to you (over-ride, re-edit w/ merged data, etc.)